# If $(H,(\cdot,\cdot))$ is a scalar product space, why can we write any $u\in H$ as $u = x+y$ where $x\in S$ and $y\in S^{\perp}$

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

If $(H,(\cdot,\cdot))$ is a scalar product space, why can we write any $u\in H$ as $u = x+y$ where $x\in S$ and $y\in S^{\perp}$?

Does this have something to do with the fact that $S^{\perp}$ is a closed? Do we also need $S$ to be a closed subspace?

Are we using that $A$ and $B$ any closed subspace then we can write $u\in H$ as $u = a+b$ with $a\in A, b\in B$?

Answer (score 0):

If we assume $S$ is a subspace of $H$.Then $H=S\bigoplus S^{\perp}$, where $S^{\perp}=\{h\in H :(h,s)=0, for\ all\ s\in S\}$ is the subspace orthogonal to $H$.

Comment: why? I know that this means, I am asking why this is true

Comment: You can see the book 'Linear Algebra Thoroughly Explained' written by Milan Vujicic on page 142 for more details.